# Linux mint: Installing Recommended Nvidia Drivers results black screen

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, nvidia

I've installed the latest Linux Mint 19.2 on my system, but I'm facing a problem when trying to install Nvidia drivers. All i did was to open the Device Manager and select the recommended ndivia-340 driver and i got a black screen after reboot.

To solve the issue I had to purge the driver and get back to nouneau.

[image: Device Manager]

`sudo apt purge nvidia*`

My notebook has a GeForce GT 720M Nvidia GPU. Any ideas on how to successfully install the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: geforce 720m is more trouble than it is worth. I would recommend just avoid using it altogether and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Wich kernel is active  ?   (display it with 'uname -a') 
I have the same problem (Linux Mint) and I have to go back to a previous kernel, so it seems to be a compatibility problem with the kernel. 
Happily, problem disappear on the next update.

To start with 'old' kernel, search with the name of your distribution:  It is normally in the grub menu, called by boot with 'shift' key pressed.

Comment: True! It seems that I can log into my laptop after booting from the old kernel. No more black screen but still I'm not sure if my nvidia card is properly running. When running:

```nvidia-settings```

I get the following output:

```~$ nvidia-settings
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
(nvidia-settings:11330): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 23:39:54.154: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed```

Comment: In the menu, search for 'Driver' entry, and install the suggested nvidia driver. This will reinstall the kernel module and probably fix the problem.